# Replace non-NaN values with their row indices within matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the 4x2 matrix A:

```
A = [2 NaN 5 8; 14 NaN 23 NaN]';
```

I want to replace the non-NaN values with their associated indices within each column in A. The output looks like this:

```
out = [1 NaN 3 4; 1 NaN 3 NaN]';
```

I know how to do it for each column manually, but I would like an automatic solution, as I have much larger matrices to handle. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Applying [**`ind2sub`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) to a mask created with [**`isnan`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) will do.

```
mask = find(~isnan(A));
[rows,~] = ind2sub(size(A),mask)
A(mask) = rows;
```

Note that the second output of `ind2sub` needs to be requested (but neglected with `~`) as well `[rows,~]` to indicate you want the output for a 2D-matrix.

---

```
A =

     1     1
   NaN   NaN
     3     3
     4   NaN

A.' =

     1   NaN     3     4
     1   NaN     3   NaN
```

Also be careful the with the two different transpose operators `'` and `.'`.

---

### Alternative

```
[n,m] = size(A);
B = ndgrid(1:n,1:m);
B(isnan(A)) = NaN;
```

or even (with a little inspiration by [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39831320/2605073))

```
[n,m] = size(A);
B = A-A + ndgrid(1:n,1:m)
```

or in one line

```
B = A-A + ndgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2))
```

Comment: Equivalently: `[rows,cols] = find(~isnan(A)); A(sub2ind(size(A), rows, cols)) = rows;`

Comment: The last two alternatives fail at zeros. `A./A` for 0 and `NaN` gives `NaN`.

Comment: @thewaywewalk You can remove that `1` here: `B = A-A +  ndgrid(1:n,1:m)` :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo well not exactly, unless I change it to an addition

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks for the answers and for tip on the difference between the two different transpose operators symbols.

Answer (score 11):

```
out = bsxfun(@times, A-A+1, (1:size(A,1)).');
```

How it works:

- `A-A+1` replaces actual numbers in `A` by `1`,  and keeps `NaN` as `NaN`
- `(1:size(A,1)).'` is a column vector of row indices
- `bsxfun(@times, ...)` multiplies both of the above with singleton expansion.

As pointed out by [@thewaywewalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2605073/thewaywewalk), in Matlab R2016 onwards `bsxfun(@times...)` can be replaced by `.*`, as singleton expansion is enabled by default:

```
out = (A-A+1) .* (1:size(A,1)).';
```

An alternative suggested by [@Dev-Il](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3372061/dev-il) is

```
out = bsxfun(@plus, A*0, (1:size(A,1)).');
```

This works because multiplying by `0` replaces actual numbers by `0`, and keeps `NaN` as is.

Comment: with Matlab 2016b its just `(A-A+1) .* (1:size(A,1)).'` isn't it?

Comment: Doing `A-A` instead of `zeros(...)` is quite clever.  Nice code golfing.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! Actually it's even golfier: `A-A` gives zero _or_ `NaN` depending on the input :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Hah! I didn't know that. Interesting.  When would it give `NaN`?

Comment: @rayryeng `x-x` is zero for any number, but not for `inf` or `NaN`. So `A-A` inserts zeros where there were numbers, and retains `NaN` entries

Comment: Ah! Well that's actually a very useful feature.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using [**`repmat`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)  and [**`isnan`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) as follows:

```
A = [ 2  NaN   5    8; 
     14  NaN  23  NaN];
out=repmat([1:size(A,2)],size(A,1),1); % out contains indexes of all the values
out(isnan(A))= NaN                     % Replacing the indexes where NaN exists with NaN
```

**Output:**

```
 1   NaN     3     4
 1   NaN     3   NaN
```

You can take the transpose if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding another answer for a couple of reasons:

1. Because overkill (**ahem** [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) **ahem**) is fun.
2. To demonstrate that `A*0` does the same as `A-A`.

```
A = [2 NaN 5 8; 14 NaN 23 NaN].';
out = A*0 + kron((1:size(A,1)).', ones(1,size(A,2)))

out =

     1     1
   NaN   NaN
     3     3
     4   NaN
```